# Entity Framework 6 - Creating dynamic repository not working / Object not match target

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, object, reflection

i'm using this code.

```
public virtual ObjectQuery<BaseObject> GetTypifiedBDOSet()
{
    MethodInfo methodInfo = typeof(ObjectQuery<BaseObject>).GetMethod("OfType", new Type[] { });
    MethodInfo genericMethodInfo = methodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(new Type[] { BDOType });
    ObjectQuery result = genericMethodInfo.Invoke(DBContext.BaseSet, null) as ObjectQuery;
    ObjectQuery<BaseObject> objectQuery = result.Cast<BaseObject>() as ObjectQuery<BaseObject>;
    return objectQuery;
}
```

But I'm getting the error that the object not match the target in line 5. (ObjectQuery result...)

I want to create a dynamic `ObjectQuery<BaseObject>` object which contains the currect query type for me.

If i create a repository dynamically i want to select all entries from database which have this type. (base class is BaseObject!)
I'm using the TPC strategy - Table per conreate.

Before the example above I used this code.

```
public virtual ObjectQuery<BaseObject> GetTypifiedBDOSet()
{
    ObjectContext objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)DBContext).ObjectContext;
    ObjectSet<BaseObject> objectSet = objectContext.CreateObjectSet<BaseObject>();
    return objectSet;
}
```

But there the problem is that i get ALL entries from database, also for example "Blogs", "Posts" and "Comments".
But i want only the `OfType<BDOType>` entries. (BDOType could be a Type of "Blog", "Post" or "Comment")

**Thanks in Advance!**

Answer (score 0):

Ah! Hours of testing it works :D

```
public virtual ObjectQuery<BaseObject> GetTypifiedBDOSet()
{
    ObjectSet<BaseObject> objectSet = ((IObjectContextAdapter)DBContext).ObjectContext.CreateObjectSet<BaseObject>();
    MethodInfo methodInfo = objectSet.GetType().GetMethod("OfType", new Type[] { });
    ObjectQuery result = methodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(new Type[] { BDOType }).Invoke(objectSet, null) as ObjectQuery;
    return (ObjectQuery<BaseObject>)result.OfType<BaseObject>();
}
```